# Check child nodes with text (*x) in different parent nodes ASP Treeview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem with my treeview.

I have two child nodes with different parents which contains a literal (*x). In this case (*1) (view image)

The code for treeview:

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" 
            onclick="ChecksArbolPermisos();" CssClass="StyleSheet1.css" 
            LineImagesFolder="~/TreeLineImages" ShowLines="False" ShowExpandCollapse="false">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Gestión de Candidatos" Value="Gestión de Candidatos" ImageUrl="1323877755_unknown.png">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Dar de alta (*1)" Value="1" ImageUrl="1323878372_user-group-new.png"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Ver grid" ImageUrl="1323878372_user-group-new.png" Value="2"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Ver Grid" ImageUrl="1323878372_user-group-new.png" Value="Ver Grid (Editar )" >
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Pruebas" Value="Pruebas" ImageUrl="1323877755_unknown.png">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Generar Informes" Value="Generar Informes" ImageUrl="1323878372_user-group-new.png"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Eliminar Pruebas" Value="Eliminar Pruebas" ImageUrl="1323878372_user-group-new.png"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Procesos" Value="Procesos" ImageUrl="1323877755_unknown.png">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Crear un nuevo proceso (*1)" Value="Crear un nuevo proceso" ImageUrl="1323878372_user-group-new.png">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
        </asp:TreeView>
```

With javascript.How can I check this nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using jquery, You can use the contains selector:

```
$("a:contains( '(*1)')")
```

UPDATE:

I tryed to make an example as yours:
In the `<head>` you need to add the jquery lib:

```
<script src="wherever/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
```

and in the end of the page (inside the body) add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a:contains('(*1)')").siblings("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked",true);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @razormad, as you requested, I changed the "li" to "a" and put a full example which works for me.